# chrome extension - force default_pop content

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

current using content_scripts to produce an alert upon url match, example:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["https://www.google.co.uk/*"],
        "js": ["alert.js"]
    }
]
```

alert.js:

```
alert( 'Hello, world!' );
```

but rather than producing an alert is it possible to force open my default_open within manifest.json?

```
"default_popup": "index.html"
```

Comment: We can not invoke a browser action by code so can no open `default_popup` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot programmatically open the pop-up and plans to make it generally available have stalled due to security concerns. You can follow its development here:

[Open Pop-Up programmatically](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=436489)